# Search funtion for dynamic input fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have dynamic parent class and in each parent class i have more than 100 subtests..i have bootstrap collapsible menu where the content will be shown or hidden with a click of a button I have dynamic class by name ep-dp-dt where i am searching input fields if i pass `ep-dp-dt[0]` i am able to search only for the zeroth class of few sub tests similarly if i pass `ep-dp-dt[1]` i am able to search only for the first class....So how can i can i pass the dynamic values in `getElementsByClassName('ep-dp-dt')[dynamic_value]` ???

```
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  tr = document.getElementsByClassName('ep-dp-dt')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
  var i;
  for(var i = 0, length = tr.length; i < length; i++) {
  td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

  if (td) {
    if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
   }  
  }
}
```

The table structure is like:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="" title="" class="form-control pull-right">

<table id="collapse1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1" class="table table-bordered table-striped collapse1 collapse in" cellspacing="0" width="100%" aria-describedby="example_info" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">

    <thead>
      <tr class="patientinfo " role="row">
      <th></th>
       <th></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="ep-dp-dt">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tbody>
</table>


<table id="collapse2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2" class="table table-bordered table-striped collapse1 collapse in" cellspacing="0" width="100%" aria-describedby="example_info" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">

    <thead>
      <tr class="patientinfo " role="row">
      <th></th>
       <th></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="ep-dp-dt">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

....
so on

Comment: How the dynamic values are passed to the function?

Comment: i am passing  <?php echo $subtests['id']; ?> from database

Comment: Could you show how you are calling the function......

Comment: yeah i have updated my table @Mamun

Comment: That is fine, but you are not calling the function *myFunction* anywhere....

Comment: i have updated @Mamun

Comment: You are using that input value in `td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter)` as *filter*.....then how that value can be used as index at the same time?

Comment: So can u pls help out how i can be dne in other way or is there any solution for that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two *input* elements, one for hide/show table based on the index and the other for the actual search string in the table.

```js
function myFunctionIndex(idx){
  document.querySelectorAll('.ep-dp-dt').forEach(function(el, i){
    if(idx.trim() == "")
      el.parentNode.style.display = "block";
    else if(i != idx)
      el.parentNode.style.display = "none";
    else
      el.parentNode.style.display = "block";
  });
}

function myFunction(el) {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  var idxVal = document.getElementById("index");
  tr = document.querySelectorAll('.ep-dp-dt tr');
  for(let i = 0, length = tr.length; i < length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].querySelectorAll("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }  
  } 
  
}
```

```html
Table Index: <input type="text" id="index" oninput="myFunctionIndex(this.value)" placeholder="" title="" class="form-control pull-right">
Search By: <input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()" placeholder="" title="" class="form-control pull-right">

<table id="collapse1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1" class="table table-bordered table-striped collapse1 collapse in" cellspacing="0" width="100%" aria-describedby="example_info" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">

  <thead>
    <tr class="patientinfo " role="row">
    <th></th>
     <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="ep-dp-dt">
       <tr>
        <td>first table data 1</td>
        <td>first table data 2</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<table id="collapse2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2" class="table table-bordered table-striped collapse1 collapse in" cellspacing="0" width="100%" aria-describedby="example_info" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">

  <thead>
    <tr class="patientinfo " role="row">
    <th></th>
     <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="ep-dp-dt">
      <tr>
        <td>second table data 1</td>
        <td>second table data 2</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: waw....working perfectly ....Thankyou so much for helping and briefing it out so clearly...thanks a lot @Mamun

Comment: @user5370838,  may I request you to accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.....thanks.